# Multiple questions that are off topic for Stack Overflow were flagged by me and I got them back as 'disputed'

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

So, I've gathered some `disputed` flags on questions that I found in the `Triage` queue and flagged as off-topic for Stack Overflow and that they should be moved to Super User or Server Fault.

My problem is: I don't know why those flags are disputed and I would like an explanation as to why these questions should remain on Stack Overflow.

Cases:

- [Apache IP range redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185588/apache-ip-range-redirection)
- [Apache and Wildfly configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142187/apache-and-wildfly-configuration)
- [How do you update every package in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051686/how-do-you-update-every-package-in-osx) ← in this case it's even worse. It's a mix between something for Super User and recommending/finding a tool

Comment: Either way, they are all bad questions and even if they made it to their 'proper' sites, they should be downvoted and closed for low quality - not migrated.

Comment: @Albzi the two Apache questions aren't that bad IMHO - at least not if they were posted on Serverfault. The IP range thingi needs some formatting/clean up but it's 'useable'.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler None of them look like good questions to me in general, but even if they were good questions on some other site, they wouldn't' be good questions *for SO* due to their topic.

Comment: OK yes they would be passable with some formatting and cleanup - your original point still stands though that they're not fit for SO in any case :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These questions should *not* remain on Stack Overflow.

However, if you look at each of the reviews, rather than the questions, you can see that the other users who reviewed your flags said that the questions looked okay, rather than that they were unsalvageable:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16758048
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16734841
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16686269

Comment: This is the unfortunate thing about community moderation, as some things may slip through which shouldn't, but imo there is nothing that can replace it and I think it works more often than not.

Comment: uh this may sound very stupid but...how do I get to that view? I mean, I sometimes see that when I flag a question as 'Looks OK' and three others did the same, but I didn't knew one could somehow navigate to that overview

Comment: @SteffenWinkler It's the exact page you were on to review them in the first place.  It's also in  your profile as an action you've taken.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler https://stackoverflow.com/users/937093/steffen-winkler?tab=activity&sort=reviews - then just click on the action you took and it will take you to that review.

Comment: @Albzi ohh, I never realized that the action I took was a link to something else than the question. Thank you!

Comment: You can also goto https://stackoverflow.com/review, click on the category and then click the "History" tab

Comment: Some guess work but could some of the "Looks OK" votes come from users who don't necessarily understand that topic and think it looks ok?

Comment: @Albzi I mean, the question don't look okay *even if you don't understand the topic*.

Comment: not sure. Anyway, what should I do in these cases? Meaning in cases where it's obvious the question doesn't belong. (Re-)Flag it?

Comment: I agree @Servy, but you get people who review just for the badge and don't really care about the review. That's another problem I guess though.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I don't even know if you're able to.  Really this is a case where you just want to have the privilege to actually vote to close, because the review doesn't invalidate that.

Comment: @Albzi It's a combination of people not actually trying to review properly as well as people who are actually trying, but just don't know how to review properly, or just have very low standards.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler worth noting that actions for completed review can be conveniently found in posts [meta-tag:timeline]s, for questions you listed these are: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45185588/timeline), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45142187/timeline), and [third](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45051686/timeline)

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I think you've done the best thing (the only thing), posted it here, that way people with more rep can take over if they agree, or set you straight if they feel you're off base. As a note, all questions have now been closed!

Comment: @George thank you. Yeah I wasn't actually too sure if I overreacted. I may or may not have only recently discovered that 'Needs Editing' is only valid if someone *else* than the original writer is able to improve the question.

Comment: I'll point out that several of these approvers hit audits soon after these reviews and were banned by the system.